# getting List of Delegation Access users of all Users

Tags: delegates, xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript, xpages-ssjs

I am working on an Application where I need to provide the List of members on which the Current User has the delegation access to mail , Calendar, Todo .

Here I am restricted to touch ACL of customer ,Only Customer can add Access Delegation Users from His mail Box with following methods.

From Mail Box->More...

1. Go to Preferences > Delegation.
2. Click Add Person or Group.
3. Specify who should have access.
4. Choose how much of your mail file you want delegates to have access to
5. Choose the tasks you want the delegate to be able to do.

Now I have Value Picker where I am trying to get all the users from "names.nsf" then getting "mail.nsf" file name by itterating each user.

But when trying go further to access the Mail Database of the user which is not in the ACL, but exist inside the Access Delegation. Throws the error that cannot access mail Db of the this User,

Below is code:

```
try{
var allowed_by:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
var db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var server_name  = db.getServer();
var name_db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(server_name,"names.nsf",false);
var name_v:NotesView = name_db.getView("($VIMPeople)");
var all_view_entries:NotesViewEntryCollection = name_v.getAllEntries();
var loggedInUser = @Name('[CANONICALIZE]',@UserName());
var entry:NotesViewEntry = all_view_entries.getFirstEntry();


while (entry != null) 
{ 
   var person_doc:NotesDocument = entry.getDocument();
   var mail_db_info = person_doc.getItemValueString("mailFile");    
   var maildb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(server_name, mail_db_info, false)

  if(maildb.isCurrentAccessPublicReader()){
     var profile_doc = maildb.getProfileDocument("calendarprofile","");
     var ReadCalendarItem:NotesItem = profile_doc.Getfirstitem("ReadCalendar");
     allowed_by.add(maildb.getFileName()); 
   }else{
     allowed_by.add("No Access");
   }
        var tmpentry = all_view_entries.getNextEntry();
        entry.recycle();
        entry = tmpentry;
}
return allowed_by;

}catch(err){
return err+"";
}
```

In above code I am trying print just the mail file name for testing , But it is not possible because the current user is not listed on all the user's Mail DB ,

But in some user Mail Access Delegation list the current user is present.

Actual Problem with Example:
User **A** is logged IN

User **B** has User **A** in his/her Access Delegation but not in Access Control List of **B's** mail DB. 
So when **A** logs IN and tries to get the User **B** in the list of Value Picker on which He/She has Delegate access (Not in ACL) then what would be the way to achieve this in the list?

Above code is converted from Lotus script to SSJS.
Reference-Link [enter link description here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21960664)

It would be really helpful as knowledge to know the above concept how it works and now how do i proceed with this requirment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read the contents of the Domain Catalog, you can do searches via the name you are looking for and then check the level of access based on the ManagerList, DesignerList, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a generell error in your assumption here: you think that ACL and Delegation in Calendar profile exist independant from each other. This is purely wrong. The calendar delegation is simply a user interface to the ACL. Whatever right you give someone via delegation is then shadowed in the ACL of the database, either directly (if user has manager access to his own mailfile) or via admin- process on the server.

So: there is no need to examine calendar profile. Just ask for „isopen“ property of database. If it is not open, then you don‘t have access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer the question "Who has access to this mailbox?" by reading the entries in the mailbox's ACL and resolving (recursively) the groups that you find. Answering the question "What mailboxes do I have access to?" can only be done with trial-and-error; e.g, by attempting to open every mail database